# How to add in a CMake project a global file extension (*.pde) to GCC which is treated like C++ code

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have a very simple CMake script. Unfortunately, the project uses a *.pde file which is plain C++ or C code.

CMake is working with any file ending, but I get a compiler error, because GCC does not know how to handle it.  How can I add a global file extension to GCC, so that the *.pde file is compiled as a usual *.cpp file?

The `-x c++ foo.pde` command is nice if I want to use the console, but for CMake it is (I think) not applicable.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(RPiCopter)

SET( RPiCopter
  absdevice
  containers
  device
  exceptions
  navigation
  frame
  vehicle
  receiver
  scheduler
  tinycopter.pde
)

message( STATUS "Include ArduPilot library directories" )
foreach( DIR ${AP_List} ${AP_List_Linux} ${AP_Headers} )
  include_directories( "../libraries/${DIR}" )
endforeach()
include_directories( zserge-jsmn )

# ***************************************
# Build the firmware
# ***************************************
add_subdirectory ( zserge-jsmn )

#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-x c++ *.pde")
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( RPiCopter ${RPiCopter} )
target_link_libraries ( RPiCopter -Wl,--start-group ${AP_List} ${AP_List_Linux} jsmn -Wl,--end-group )
```

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use [`set_source_files_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/set_source_files_properties.html) along with the [`LANGUAGE`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html) property to mark the file(s) as C++ sources:

```
set_source_files_properties(${TheFiles} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
```

As @steveire pointed out in his own answer, [this bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14516) will require something like the following workaround:

```
set_source_files_properties(${TheFiles} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
  add_definitions("-x c++")
endif()
```

Comment: The `set_source_file_properties()` call is IMO the right way to do it, but I would replace the global `add_definitions()` call to `set_source_properties(${TheFiles} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-x c++")` to limit the definitions to just those files

Comment: @jairo I agree. `add_definitions` does not work well in case a multi-lang project is built like `project(casm C ASM_NASM)`.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should be able to just extend `CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS`. This would help, if you have a lot of files with unknown file extensions.

But this variable is not cached - as e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is - so the following code in [CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake.in](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake.in) will always overwrite/hide whatever you will set:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS inl;h;hpp;HPP;H;o;O;obj;OBJ;def;DEF;rc;RC)
set(CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS C;M;c++;cc;cpp;cxx;mm;CPP)
```

I consider this non-caching being [a bug in CMake](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=8851), but until this is going to be changed I searched for a workaround considering the following:

- You normally don't want to change files in your CMake's installation
- It won't have any effect if you change `CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` after `project()`/`enable_language()` (as discussed [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.cmake.user/32203)).

I have successfully tested the following using one of the "hooks"/configuration variables inside `CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake.in`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_SYSROOT_FLAG_CODE "list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS pde)")

project(RPiCopter CXX)

message("CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS ${CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS}")

add_executable(RPiCopter tinycopter.pde)
```

Answer (score 3):

I decided to use this approach. I just remove the file ending by cmake in the temporary build directory. 
So GCC is not confused anymore because of the strange Arduino *.pde file extension.

```
# Exchange the file ending of the Arduino project file
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tinycopter.pde ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tinycopter.cpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

CMake doesn't do this for you:

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14516

Comment: I've added further info to my answer which seems to get round the issue.

Comment: I doubt this is true, but doesn't solve the problem. 
It would be nice, to have something like a wrapper for all the different compilers and file extensions. 
I use now configure_file. It is not elegant but works.

Comment: It is true. It doesn't matter if it doesn't solve the problem. It's just the correct answer.