# How to add files that are not used to create the target in the target project (cmake)

Tags: c++, cmake

Let me use a simple example to illustrate my problem, and suppose now I have the following files:

```
src
---CMakeLists.txt
---a.h
---a.cpp
---script.py
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` file, a target called `lib_proj` is created:

```
add_library(lib_proj STATIC a.h a.cpp)
```

Then in Visual Studio, we can see an object target called `'lib_proj'` is created, which includes `a.h` and `a.cpp`. Then how can **`script.py`** be added to this target as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_library(lib_proj STATIC a.h a.cpp script.py)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid that those additional files will not contribute to the static library building.

Comment: What do you mean by contribute? You will see them in VS, but obviously they will not be compiled or part of static library.

Comment: You won't need `CMakeLists.txt` because that's added by CMake itself to the VS project. The C++ extensions handled by CMake: `set(CMAKE_CXX_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS inl;h;hpp;HPP;H;o;O;obj;OBJ;def;DEF;rc;RC)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS C;M;c++;cc;cpp;cxx;mm;CPP)` (see [How to add in a CMake project a global file extension (*.pde) to GCC which is treated like C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556429/how-to-add-in-a-cmake-project-a-global-file-extension-pde-to-gcc-which-is-tr)). I assume you have to add `set_source_files_properties(script.py PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY 1)`.