# CMake: what are possible target source types and can they be extended?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In CMake, one can define a target, for example a C or C++ library, with [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/add_library.html), with the following syntax:

```
add_library(<name> [STATIC | SHARED | MODULE]
            [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL]
            [source1] [source2 ...])
```

But what are possible kind of sources? They can be `.h` or `.cxx` files containing code obviously. But they can also be `.rc` resources files, or even `.obj` object files used by the linker.

So what types of "non-code" are allowed as sources of a target in CMake, depending on the language, target type, platform? The page on [`SOURCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/prop_tgt/SOURCES.html#prop_tgt:SOURCES) is rather uninformative. Is it located somewhere else in the documentation?

Also, can this list of allowed source types be customized and extended, and how?

**EDIT**

As an example, objects provided as sources of a target are used everywhere in tensorflow's CMake files, [for example here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/tf_tutorials.cmake#L19).

Comment: I think it's hardcoded: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmSourceFile.h#L126-L133

Comment: As for what I could find in the docs: see the [`LANGUAGE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html) property on source files

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24534384/1896169

Comment: @Justin Thanks! But how come `.obj` is not in the regex? It is definitely handled though. This does not cover the whole story probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of supported extensions mainly depends on the [`ENABLED_LANGUAGES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/ENABLED_LANGUAGES.html).

So if I grep for [`CMAKE_<LANG>_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS.html) I'll get the following list:

```perl
set(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS "s;S;asm")
set(CMAKE_C_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS             "c;m")
set(CMAKE_CSharp_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS        "cs")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS          "cu")
set(CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS           "C;M;c++;cc;cpp;cxx;mm;CPP")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS       "f;F;fpp;FPP;f77;F77;f90;F90;for;For;FOR;f95;F95")
set(CMAKE_Java_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS          "java")
set(CMAKE_RC_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS            "rc;RC")
set(CMAKE_Swift_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS         "swift")
```

**The special cases**

There are some special cases with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) like [`add_library(... $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib> ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) and outputs of [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files) calls.

**Edit**: The use of object files as source files is actually [a sub-case of the `add_custom_command()` special case](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/70b4e1051e04be892c86aa3ff729d63ccf1f7771) implemented in [`cmSourceFile::CheckExtension()`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Source/cmSourceFile.cxx#L213):

> ```
>  // Look for object files.
>  if (this->Extension == "obj" || this->Extension == "o" ||
>      this->Extension == "lo") {
>    this->SetProperty("EXTERNAL_OBJECT", "1");
>  }
> ```

**How to extend the supported source file extensions/types?**

Examples can be found here

- [How to add in a CMake project a global file extension (*.pde) to GCC which is treated like C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556429/how-to-add-in-a-cmake-project-a-global-file-extension-pde-to-gcc-which-is-tr)
- [Generic rule from makefile to cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293535/generic-rule-from-makefile-to-cmake)

Comment: Yes, you can really specify an object as a source. I added an example in my question.

Comment: @user209974 Ok, I've found the code part in CMake doing this and updated my answer. But that seems very undocumented or at least I couldn't find a hint for this in the official documentation.